# XStream- not include some values

Tags: java, serialization, xstream

I want to include objects from 3 different classes in one xml.

I am planning to created another class to hold a list of these objects.

I need only subset of values from these objects.

Is there a way to omit few values while generating xml from XStream?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the @XStreamOmitField annotation.

Take a look at the documentation here: http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html#OmitField

The below is from the documentation:

```
@XStreamAlias("message")
class RendezvousMessage {

  @XStreamOmitField
  private int messageType;

  @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="part")
  private List<String> content;

  @XStreamConverter(value=BooleanConverter.class, booleans={false}, strings={"yes", "no"})
  private boolean important;

  @XStreamConverter(SingleValueCalendarConverter.class)
  private Calendar created = new GregorianCalendar();

  public RendezvousMessage(int messageType, boolean important, String... content) {
    this.messageType = messageType;
    this.important = important;
    this.content = Arrays.asList(content);
  }
}
```